# disable text selection except input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this snippet of code to disable all text selection.  How would I go about disabling all text except for input? I tried  `$('* :not(input)').disableTextSelect();` but it disabled selection for everything (input included)

```
$.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function () {
                return this.each(function () {
                    if ($.browser.mozilla) {//Firefox
                        $(this).css('MozUserSelect', 'none');
                    } else if ($.browser.msie) {//IE
                        $(this).bind('selectstart', function () { return false; });
                    } else {//Opera, etc.
                        $(this).mousedown(function () { return false; });
                    }
                });
            });
            $('* :not(input)').disableTextSelect();
```

Comment: Are you sure the * is necessary? Try $(":not(input)")

Comment: Note that disabling selection changes the default behaviour of the browser and will confuse or even annoy the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in IE and FF:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //Disable default text selection behavior
        toggleEnableSelectStart(false);

        //for inputs it must be possible to select text
        jQuery("input[type=text]").focusin(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
        jQuery("input[type=text]").mouseover(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
        jQuery("input[type=text]").focusout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });
        jQuery("input[type=text]").mouseout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });

    });

    function toggleEnableSelectStart(enable) {
        document.onmousedown = function (e) { return enable; };
        document.onselectstart = function (e) { return enable; }; ;
    }
```

Comment: Works for me in IE, FF, Opera & Chrome

Answer (score 14):

```
$(document).bind('mousedown selectstart', function(e) {
    return $(e.target).is('input, textarea, select, option, html');
});
```

Thanks to @user2873592, who mentioned that adding `html` here would fix the chrome scroll bar can't be dragged issue.

Comment: just pasted it inside document.ready and it worked like a charm !! thanks a lot @deerchao

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that this disabling is inherited.  So, even though you aren't selected them in the $() they still get disabled.  But this can also be in our favor.

After disabling, you can enable the inputs.

```
$('body').css('MozUserSelect', '-moz-none');
$('input').css('MozUserSelect', 'text');
```

NOTE: the value must be '-moz-none'.  If 'none', it can't be changed.

I can't test IE nor do I have a solution for Opera.  But maybe this will help part way.